# Deserialize MsgPack with anonymous list in C++

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization, variant, msgpack

Imagine a list with few structures with fields of different types

```
 "[{ "field1":"b"
     "field2": 7  },

   { "field1":"e",
     "field2": 8  },

   { "field1":"g",
     "field2": 3  }]"
```

I receive bytes serialized with MsgPack. I want to deserialize it. How can I do this?

With Qt implementation of MsgPack ([QMsgPack](https://github.com/romixlab/qmsgpack)) it is possible to use QVariantList which could contain different types inside a list and a method toList(). It would be something like this:

```
QVariantList list = MsgPack::unpack(receivedBytes).toList();
```

But i cannot use Qt libraries due to limitations of the project. How can I deserialize anonymous list of structures?

p.s. Not to mention: i cannot know the length of a incoming list.

Comment: Looking at the spec, the MsgPack format is self-framing, as every collection seems to embed an element count. So you could simply accumulate bytes into a buffer and ask a MsgPack parser if it has enough data to decode. I picked [this library](https://github.com/mikeloomisgg/cppack/tree/master) at random from the msgpack website and it  reports `OutOfRange` if it does not have sufficient data in the buffer.

Comment: @Botje thanks but how can I handle the variative length of a list? Should I decode received bytes with something like a msgpack::unpack<List<MyStruct>>(Bytes, NumOfBytes)?

Comment: If you have no other framing method, just accumulate bytes into a buffer and ask your msgpack library to decode a msgpack object from it. Either it fails or it succeeds. But the msgpack encoding *knows* how many items it must contain.